# Integral with respect to Brownian motion, Variance

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Good day. Imagene we have a martingale $M(t)=\int_0^t f(s)dB(s)$ which satisfies Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz Theorem. At the same time $M(t)^2 - <M>(t)$ is a Martingale starting in $0$ as well. If i am not mistaken, then from Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz Theorem i could conclude that 
\begin{align*}
M(t) \sim N(0,\int_0^t f(s)^2ds)
\end{align*}
On another side $\mathbb{V}(M(t))=\mathbb{E}(M(t)^2)=\mathbb{E}(<M>(t))$. It follows that 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\int_0^t f(s)^2ds)=\int_0^t f(s)^2ds
\end{align*}
If $f(s)$ is deterministic, then it is not a problem, but what if not? I am sure there is a mistake somewhere in my thoughts. Good if someone could fix it :)

Comment: How do you conclude $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds \right) = \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds $$ ....?

Comment: @saz DDB theorem gave me $M(t)$ is gaussian with variance $\int_0^t f(s)^2ds$, do you agree on that?
But if i compute it directly, then $\mathbb{V}(M(t))=\mathbb{E}(M(t)^2) - (\mathbb{E}(M(t)))^2=\mathbb{E}(<M>_t)=\mathbb{E}(\int_0^t f(s)^2ds)$.

Comment: No, I don't agree. The variance of a variable is deterministic, right? So, $\int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds$ cannot be the variance of $M_t$ if $f$ is not deterministic. The DDB theorem gives also that the variance equals $$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds \right).$$

Comment: @saz yes, nondeterministic variance in my case is troubling me.

Tell me please what i do wrong here:
DDB allows me to represent my Martingale $M(t)=B_{<M>_t}$ for $B$ a Brownian motion. But $B \sim N(0, <M>_t)$ and so is $M(t)$ then. This way i come to variance equals $<M>_t$, where
\begin{align*}
<M>_t=\int_0^t f(s)^2ds
\end{align*}

Comment: I see; so you want to replace "t" in $\mathbb{E}(B_t^2) = t$ by "$\langle M \rangle_t$", right? But this doesn't work, you cannot simply replace something deterministic by a random variable. More generally, $$\mathbb{E}f(x,Y) = g(x)$$ for some functions $f,g$ does not imply $$\mathbb{E}f(X,Y) = g(X)$$ for any random variable $X$.

Comment: @saz yes, i understand it. So even though it is $M(t)=B_{<M>_t}$ by DDB, but when it comes to distribuon it is $B_{<M>_t} \sim N(0,\mathbb{E}<M>_t)$, right? Sad it isn't stated in DDB.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: OP: I wish to differ, actually $B_{\langle M\rangle_t}$ need not even be normal. For a simpler case, consider $X=B_T$ where $T$ is $1$ or $2$ with equal probabilities and independent of $B$. Then $X$ is not normal, since its density is $f=\frac12(g_1+g_2)$, with $g_t$ the (normal) density of $B_t$, and this density $f$ is (clearly, I hope) not normal. (Rather, in full generality, $X$ is distributed as $\sqrt{T}\cdot B_1$.) @saz